# Qual o problema com esta concatenação?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, get, concatenação-de-string

```
$('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl);
                $('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&teste='+$('#cidades'));
```

Na linha acima em negrito não consigo colocar na variável `teste` o valor do parâmetro `#cidades` que é recebido na linha de cima. Como resolver esta situação, pois preciso que o parametro `#cidade` seja levado em GET pela variável `teste`

Comment: Olá Gladison, percebi que você teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente. Recomendo que para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta faça um [tour] e leia o guia [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com $('#cidades') você não está pegando nenhum valor. Está pegando um Objeto.

Caso #cidades seja um input, utilize

```
$('#cidades').val()
```

Repare que você fez corretamente com $('#Estados'), utilizando o .val(), mas caso $("#cidades") não seja um input você não conseguirá pegar o valor que deseja.